# Is this an injury or a disease?? I just got the goldfish

Tags: fish, goldfish

[image: couldn't do anything]
Its been swimming around a lot maybe it hit the tank?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! If it is not constantly rubbing this spot onto something, then it is some kind of skin infection. If you did not sat it in a tank to other fish, you should not do it. Instead have it in quarantine, until you know what exactly it is and started treatment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [White patch and spot on my goldfish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/white-patch-and-spot-on-my-goldfish)

Comment: i think it's different,t it could be ammonia burns cause they were in a horrible condition when i got them (yellow water) the other fish look unaffected tho

Comment: Isdk if it's ammonia burn, kinda doubting it rn but ive noticed that it IS rubbing itself on the wall but the area of contact is usually the mouth part